# Listing which repository a package will be installed from using yum

Tags: yum, installation, package-management

I am trying to run yum completely from local repositories. How do I tell if yum is using some other repositories? Is there a way to list the locations from which yum is getting the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run "yum install" and check the output it should give you the name of the repository that it going to use to install the package, and its deps like so;

```
==================================================================================
 Package            Arch            Version              Repository           Size
==================================================================================
Installing:
 evolution          x86_64          3.6.4-3.fc18         updates               8.7 M
Installing for dependencies:
 gtkhtml3           x86_64          4.6.4-1.fc18         updates               808 k
 libytnef           x86_64          1.5-9.fc18           fedora                29 k
```

If you run `yum deplist package` like so, yum will give you some more information regarding how it is resolving the dependencies for the package;

```
$ sudo yum deplist evolution
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, presto
package: evolution.i686 3.6.4-3.fc18
  dependency: /bin/sh
   provider: bash.x86_64 4.2.45-1.fc18
  dependency: gnome-icon-theme >= 2.30.2.1
   provider: gnome-icon-theme.noarch 3.6.2-1.fc18
  dependency: gvfs
   provider: gvfs.x86_64 1.14.2-4.fc18
   provider: gvfs.i686 1.14.2-4.fc18
  dependency: libICE.so.6
```

However you can force it to use your specific local repo, i.e. replace as appropriate with your named local repo, and disable all the others with the appropriate options for enable and disable repos `--disablerepo=* --enablerepo=<your local repo here>` so;

```
$ sudo yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=fedora install evolution
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, presto
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package evolution.x86_64 0:3.6.2-3.fc18 will be installed
...
---> Package libytnef.x86_64 0:1.5-9.fc18 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==========================================================================================
 Package              Arch             Version              Repository      Size
======================================================================================
Installing:
 evolution            x86_64           3.6.2-3.fc18          fedora         8.7 M
Installing for dependencies:
 gtkhtml3             x86_64           4.6.1-1.fc18          fedora         806 k
 libytnef             x86_64           1.5-9.fc18            fedora         29 k

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+2 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 9.5 M
Installed size: 47 M
```

This last method will either install the package and its dependencies from the named repo, (or fail with the explanation as the error message.)